# Is there an instance where 'and' could not replace 'but'?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

For instance, I would normally write the following sentence:

> Many were the dangers arrayed against me, but I had no fear.

Is it grammatically incorrect to write instead:

> Many were the dangers arrayed against me, and I had no fear.

I noticed this whilst speaking with a co-worker, and found he extremely rarely used the conjunction 'but', favoring 'and' instead. Though it sounds strange to me, I cannot find anything to say this is grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I have no choice but to think long and hard about this challenge.

Comment: Many instances of "but" could be replaced by "and" without a loss of factual accuracy, but the meaning and connotations of what was meant by the sentence would almost always change.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer sooner- I was making a peanut butter but jelly sandwich.

Comment: @Jim: It's worth pointing out that the question asks about replacing _but_ with _and_, but not the other way around. It's much easier to think of examples where _and_ cannot be replaced by _but_ than vice versa.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conjunction ***but*** means the same thing as the conjunction ***and***, in most cases. They both contrast with the disjunction ***or***.

There are plenty of idioms that use *but*, like [*but for that*, *nothing but the best*](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf), *But why?*, and the like, but in normal use [the logic is the same](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

The difference between *and* and *but* in non-idiomatic usage is that
*but* carries a presupposition that something else was expected.

- *Bill washed the dishes and Mary dried them.*
  (no presupposition)
- *Bill washed the dishes but Mary dried them.*
  (presupposes that Mary was not expected to dry them)

Other words can be used to implicate expectations, like *beside(s), except,* or *instead (of)*, but they're not coordinating conjunctions like *and, or,* and *but*.

Answer (score 0):

‘And’ and ‘but’ are coordinators. ‘Instead’ isn’t. It’s an adverb, so it cannot be grammatically substituted for either. However, in speech, it’s not always easy to identify sentence boundaries.

Comment: Did you misunderstand the question? Both mentions of 'instead' in the question are merely using it within the sentences: discussing using the word "and" *instead of using* the word "but".