# What is the difference between these two sentences? "If A is true, then B is true" and "Since A is true, B is true"

Tags: grammaticality, logic

Consider the following two sentences:

> 1. If A is true, then we can conclude that B is true.
> 2. Since A is true, we can conclude that B is true.

I have two questions:

1. What is the difference between two sentences above?
2. "Since A is true, **then** we can conclude that B is true." Is this sentence correct?

Comment: 1 is purely hypothetical. 2 asserts that A ***is*** true and therefore so is B.

Comment: Please don't ask question 2. That's proof-reading. See "How can I ask about checking my text?" in the [Help pages](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the second question first, *then* is optional after *if*; also after *since*, but not as common.

The first question, however, involves an important distinction. Whereas *if* is a standard hypothetical, *since* has a ***Presupposition***.

A presupposition is something that has to be true in order for the sentence to make sense. If I tell you that

- *Bill's brother is visiting me*

then you have to believe

- *Bill has a brother*

in order to understand what I told you.

One feature of presuppositions is that they can't be negated. If I tell you

- *Bill's brother isn't visiting me*

you still have to believe Bill has a brother to understand it.

This property of presuppositions distinguishes them from assertions like *Bill has a brother*, which can be denied:

- *Bill has a brother ~ Bill doesn't have a brother.*

Language is full of presuppositions -- they're one kind of "connotation", which is a cover term for a variety of phenomena like this. Presuppositions distinguish [*and* from *but*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/123199/15299), and [*used to be* from *isn't any more*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/72205/15299), and *accuse* from *criticize*, and [many more](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf).

*Since* means 'if it's true, and we all know it's true, that ...'; it's used to consider implications, while restricting discussion of details of the presupposed clause. Essentially it says the material in the clause it introduces is background; nothing to see here, move along.

That's why presuppositions are prominent in all propaganda. If you can make someone think that everyone else believes `X`, they are likely to conclude that they must believe `X`, too.